# How to deploy a node js app to s3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Can AWS S3 hold a node js app? Because I have a front-end serverless app, and don't know how to let it interact with lambda function

Comment: s3 is a storage service!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store a NodeJS codebase in S3 but it won't be executed since S3 is for the purpose of serving static content. If you want to have a NodeJS environment in AWS there are couple of options available.

- EC2 instance with NodeJS
- Using [Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/Welcome.html)
- Using [AWS ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) (If you plan to dockerize the NodeJS app)
- AWS Lambda (This you need to tailor your application to fit in)

Comment: Thanks! right now I just know how to deploy a lambda function, but when it comes to front-end app, I don't know where to put all those app  files in order to work with lambda function.

Comment: Hi @Ben, did you solve your doubts about front-end coding?